# Can't Restore Backup using ClockworkMod Recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, 4.3-jelly-bean

I wonder can anyone help. I done a backup using Clorkwork Mod before I flashed a new ROM onto my phone. Now when i am trying to restore the backup onto the phone using CWM it completes the task but whenever I reboot the phone it gets passed the first samsung screen but hangs at the second SAMSUNG screen where the text is pulsing.

I have tried Wipe / Data factory reset, Wipe Cache, Wipe Dalvick and fix permissions. None of these seem to make any difference. The only thing that has worked in flashing a new ROM but I do not want to lose any of my apps /configs.

Any suggestions guys would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for at leat 15-30 minutes where it hangs?

Comment: Yes, I left it sitting for a quite a long period of time.\

Comment: What phone are you using? Is it an S4 with KNOX enabled. Are you trying to downgrade from 4.3 to 4.2.2 with a KNOX bootloader?

Comment: S4 i9505. It has 4.3.3 I then flashed with Cyanogen and Android 4.2.2 which worked fine. I now want to restore back to my original stock 4.3.3 backup that I made. But it just freezes at the samsung screen. So I downgraded. But now Im looking to restore back to the original stock.. It had KNOX enabled yes as I use to get annoying error messages about apps getting blocked.

Comment: Can you get the stock firmware from Sammobile, then flash back to stock recovery and flash triangle away to get back from 'custom' status. Have you tripped KNOX? You can't flash Stock firware with a custom recovery. Have you followed this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2265477 Backup your apps with Titanium Backup or Carbon (or other alternatives)

Comment: If I flash the stock firmware from Sammobile will I then be able to restore my backup? What is flashing triangle? I have done a backup of the apps with Titanium. Will this have the details for the apps stored such as user accounts, settings etc. ?

Comment: Ok you can restore your backups with Titanium, but afaik you'll need root on your stock rom. "Triangle Away" is an appliction that resets your 'flash counter' and changes your status from 'Custom' to 'official'. Titanium restores the full app and data, so for example, your facebook will restore the last backup, logged in already etc! I hope that helps. Don't take this wrong, but before you go flashing like mad read up on a few threads there on XDA and be sure exactly what you want to do and what the risks are! It's very  hard to completely brick a device... but I've a dead S4 here.

Comment: When you refer to my stock rom, do you mean my original backup or the one you have recommended I flash to replace it. My backup had root. Ah yes I have heard of this Triangle Away, but never done it. Yes thanks I had read a bit but possibly should have read some more. Had flashed my HTC Wildfire before but that was a much less expensive phone admittedly.Would be nice though if I could figure out how to restore that old backup. Seems a bit pointless having that feature in CWM if it doesnt work :(

Comment: The option does usually work. Personally I never use CWM (I used AmonRA back in the day and Philz recovery now). The issue MAY (I'm not 100% sure) but with Samsung's new KNOX bootloader that does not allow a downgrade, i.e. your backup is an older version of android. It's madness and has caused a large backlash agains Samsung in the dev community. I've just put a Google Edition ROM on and I'm sticking with it for now. Maybe 4.4 when it is more stable. I just restored a 4.3 backup in about 3 mins this morning but a 4.2.2 gets bootlooped like you I'm afraid.

Comment: Cool. You recommend Philz then? I just read a lot about CWM so figured it was the best. Yea im not convinced its boot loader related. As my backup was 4.3.3 and the version of the ROM which I had flashed was 4.2.2 so surely the ROM would allow it as its a newer version. Perhaps I should have disabled KNOX before capturing backup if thats possible? I had Trust Security Anti Virus stuff installed on my backup too. I wonder could that have been related to my restore issue?